# Getting error [Error: Data intent is null] while requesting auth token from azure active directory in react natve

Tags: android, react-native, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I am trying to authenticate through Azure Active Directory on a React native app using the react-native-app-auth package which is also the official package for this task. I have made the app registration, and successfully made it return me the "auth code" instead of "auth token", also I was able to make the mobile app redirected to the required screen. But right after returning me the "auth code" it says

> [Error: Data intent is null]

The code I am using is below

```
import { authorize } from "react-native-app-auth";
import pkceChallenge from 'react-native-pkce-challenge';

const config = {
    clientSecret: "MY_SECRET_VALUE_FROM_AAD",
    issuer: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY_TENANT_VALUE_FROM_AAD',
    clientId: 'MY_CLIENT_ID_AT_AAD',
    redirectUrl: 'com.sham://com.sham/android/callback',
    scopes: [
        'opened', 
        'profile', 
        'email', 
    ],
    additionalParameters: {prompt: 'select_account'},
    serviceConfiguration: {
        authorizationEndpoint: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
        tokenEndpoint:'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    },
};

try {
    const result = await authorize(config);
} catch (err){
    console.log(err)
}

// ALSO THROUGH
const challenge = pkceChallenge();
try {
    const result = await authorize({...config, code_challenge: challenge.codeChallenge, code_challenge_method: "S256"});
} catch (err){
    console.log(err)
}
```

I have also tried to install the demo app at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-react-native but that app never gets installed maybe due to old dependencies. Please point out if someone knows what mistake I might be committing.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the scheme which you have given in `AndroidManifest.xml` and
in `build.gradle`

`manifestPlaceholders = [ appAuthRedirectScheme: 'yourScheme' ]`

both must not be same. in case it is same for you, add some suffix in the build.gradle manifestPlaceholders
ex: `yourScheme.auth` and update the same in the redirectUrl in Azure portal.

Comment: which scheme ? its not making any sense to me at least

Comment: `<data android:scheme="yourScheme" />` in AndroidManifest and `manifestPlaceholders = [ appAuthRedirectScheme: 'yourScheme.auth' ]` in build.gradle should be different